# Refering to a different control in each iteration of a loop

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In my program I have 24 text boxes that the user uses for input. I want to assign the contents of each text box to an index of an array. Is there a way I can do this in a loop without having to type out `strItems(0) = MainForm.txtEntry1.text` every time? This is written in Visual Basic.

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    For intCount = 0 to (strItems.length - 1)
      strItems(intCount) = txtEntry[intCount + 1]
    Next
```

Comment: Not that the collection of controls you work with is the "container's" collection. Only if all controls are on the form surface will the controls be in Me.Controls. As Kevin noted you can use a name suffix to act as an index. The Tag property may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefix all of you text boxes names (e.g. textBoxArray1) you can then loop through all the text boxes on the form and process accordingly. Like:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
   If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
      If(ctrl.Name.StartsWith("textBoxArray") Then
          'your code here
      End If
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely going to make my life a lot easier.

Comment: You could also say `If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then`.

Comment: Used both of your guy's suggestions. Text boxes were in a group box so it didn't work at first. Is there a way I can do this with the text boxes in a group box?

Comment: You can do `For Each ctrl In MyGroupBox.Controls`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to put controls into an array.

```
Dim Array() As TextBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(c) c.Name.Contains("")).ToArray()
Array.Reverse(Array)
```

Where you see the empty quotes, like @Kevin said, you can prefix your names to find only those Textboxes and fill those, or you can leave it blank like I have and it will index every single textbox on your form into the array.

Then you can use something like this to access the TextBox

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Array(i).Text = "Stuff"
```