# Select all TextBox from a Windows Forms and add specific text to each one?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm with 6 `TextBoxes` (`txtNumber1`, `txtNumber2`, ...). When I click the button, I generate 6 random numbers and add they to a `ArrayList`, and then I want to put 1 of these numbers in each of the `TextBox`.

I can do this by doing `txtNumber1.Text = arraylist[0];` and so on...

I wonder if there is a way I can do this like I would do with JavaScript using a `for` loop, just changing the number of the `TextBox` id and avoid having to add the numbers one by one.

Comment: How to correctly answer this question depends on how you are creating the controls. The marked duplicate offers a number of options, at least one of which should work for you. See also the answer here: [Refering to a different control in each iteration of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29926244). It's in VB.NET, but it's still .NET and works exactly the same. If you want specific help, please post a new question with [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you are doing and why your question isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (TextBox control in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
     (control).Text = arraylist[i].ToString();
     i++;
}
```

This iterate through all `TextBoxes` of the form and set their texts to `ArrayList`'s values. Of course the count of the `TextBoxes` and the `ArrayList`'s length should be same then this code should works fine for you.