# C# winform iterate textbox property

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new with C# and trying to iterate values of 4 textboxes on my winform application, before i look into list arrays, is it possible to loop all 4 of the textboxes appending the index number?

Example

```
for(i =0; i == 4; i++){
   textBox_+ i +.Text
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763869/2946329

Comment: You could just make a list with all textboxes `this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, though you do it slightly differently. You need to iterate over the `Control` collection and search for your textboxes.
E.g.

```cs
foreach (var textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    textBox.Text = "bla";
}
```

If you want to access only certain textboxes - you could tag them via `Tag` property and search only for those. E.g.

```cs
foreach (var textBox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    if (textBox.Tag == "sometag")
        textBox.Text = "bla";
}
```

Comment: I would create a List<TextBox> of maybe a Dictonary<string, TextBox> instead of always iterating over all controls.

Comment: The answer as always "it depends". Extra lists and dictionaries will use extra memory, and it may be an acceptable trade off, or not.

Comment: True. Although four names and addresses can hardly be considered a burden. We do't know how many controls will be there nor how often they have be to be searched. Added bonus: It would allow excluding other Textboxes on the form or including nested ones. But it will be good enough for jazz..